# Transfer eth to other account

Tags: solidity

I want to write a function let user deposit a fixed amount of eth to a specific address for registering purpose.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Election {
    // Constructor
    address public chairman;

    constructor () public {
      chairman = msg.sender;
    }

    function register() public payable{
        chairman.transfer(1.0);
    }
}
```

But this error threw out

> member 'transfer' not found or not visible after argument-dependent
>   lookup in address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to transfer ETH to an address, it has to be marked as `payable`, so you have to use `address payable public chairman;`.